# How can I install, correctly, geopandas on python?

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to install geopandas on python 3.10 microsoft version but with "pip install geopandas" there are some errors and with "conda install geopandas", apparently, it install, but in a second moment when I want to run my code, Python doesn't recognize geopandas in the line "import geopandas as gp". According to you, what is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  There are is probably nothing special about geopandas in this regard, so you might find your answer by seaching the hundreds of other answers regarding `ModuleNotFoundError` and other import problems.  As with most of these it is most likely you are not running the same Python interpreter you were using when you tried to install it, or the other way around.  If you got "some errors" please post them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install geopandas on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958421/pip-install-geopandas-on-windows)

Comment: geopandas is a *bit* special, in that it's not a pure-python package and installing with pip can be very tough. conda is the recommended install method. did you activate your environment?